# What is the advantage of using brackets in this notation verses the other

Tags: c++, syntax, coding-style

I've heard from all of my professors that this is how brackets should be used when coding in ***C++***:

```
void hereIsAFunc(){
  //Code
}
```

Yet, I don't understand why you would ever want to do this when you could do:

```
void hereIsAFunc()
{
  //Code
}
```

It looks way cleaner to me, is there a specific advantage that the first has over the other? What is the reason that this is the "standard" in coding?

Comment: It's not *the* standard. It's *a* standard. One which many don't follow.

Comment: The first placement lets you save a significant number of code lines, so the same screen can fit a lot more code.

Comment: @dasblinkenlight What you said is really the only answer that would make sense in regards to the advantages of the first over the second. The -3 down votes are also mysterious to me.

Comment: @Yusha The downvotes are a result of your question being a poor fit this the Q&A site. The site has long banned questions that call for answers based on opinion (as opposed to questions that could be answered based on facts). Such questions are promptly placed on hold.

Comment: @dasblinkenlight Though your response is insightful and clear, it still averts the reality that my question is being down voted based on premises I didn't know - otherwise, think about it, why would I ask that question in the first place if I knew it was a opinion based question? I was assuming there was  a technical reason for why people use one method over the other, so your response is substantial but ultimately is pretty weak for an explanation of why you would down vote me. Anyways, it doesn't matter, people will do what they want out of their own spite.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your professor has a personal style for indenting and formatting code. There is no "standard", anywhere, that specifies that this is the "right" or the "wrong" way to format the code.

Unlike certain languages, that will remain nameless, that for some odd reason are sensitive to whitespace and indentation, whitespace indentation is mostly irrelevant in C++.

Your professor's preferred style is neither right, nor wrong, nor a standard of any kind. You should simply nod your head in class, submit your homework assignments using your professor's preferred formatting style, get a good grade, then simply forget you heard the whole thing after the class is over.

Comment: Considering whether to -1 or not because clearly his professors should be burned at the stake for their heresy.

Comment: This is what I was told. I am asking a question in regards to what I told. It does not deserve negative votes. Whose fault is it that I was told this by someone who has a Masters in Computer Science?

Comment: I agree with you. I do not agree with the negative votes on this question. This was a legitimate question. Simple, perhaps, and a little bit naive, but there was nothing wrong with your question. But, my vote carries no more weight than anyone else's vote.

Answer (score -1):

It's just a style preference. Except for figuring out >> vs. > > or << vs. < < , the compiler doesn't care about white space.